# How to get side by side data by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I can run to get the average order value over a specific time period, but I would like to be able to get each day during that time period in one column and the value in the second column.

**This is how I would like the data:**

```
Day          AOV
1/1/2015     342.83
1/2/2015     312.39
```

**Here's my current code to retrieve just one average value from a specific time period:**

```
SELECT  (sum(oi.price * oi.qty) / count(distinct o.orderid)) AS AOV
FROM    dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersItems oi ON oi.orderID = o.orderID
WHERE   o.orderDate between '5/20/2015' AND '8/20/2015'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `o.orderDate` happens to be a `DATETIME` with hours/minutes/seconds, rather than just a date:

```
SELECT  convert(date, o.orderDate) as orderDate
(sum(oi.price * oi.qty) / count(distinct o.orderid)) AS AOV
FROM    dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersItems oi ON oi.orderID = o.orderID
group by convert(date, o.orderDate)
WHERE   o.orderDate between '5/20/2015' AND '8/20/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  o.orderDate as "Day", (sum(oi.price * oi.qty) / count(distinct o.orderid)) AS AOV
FROM    dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersItems oi ON oi.orderID = o.orderID
WHERE   o.orderDate between '5/20/2015' AND '8/20/2015'
GROUP BY o.OrderDate /* or cast(o.OrderDate as date) if it's a datetime */
ORDER BY "Day"
```

If `orderDate` is a datetime then you need to be careful about the end of the range. Your query will include midnight on the final day but nothing else afterward. I suspect this isn't the case though.